# html class value is not getting recognized in js file

Tags: javascript

the class created in index.html is not getting recognized in my js file.

```
<div class="clockcontainer">
    <div class="hour"></div>
    <div class="minutes"></div>
    <div class="seconds"></div>

</div>
```

js file

```
hour.style.transform = `rotate(${hrotation}deg)`;
minutes.style.transform = `rotate(${mrotation}deg)`;
seconds.style.transform = `rotate(${srotation}deg)`;
```

I got this error in console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: hour is not defined
    at index.js:10:5
```

Comment: Class names don't become global variables automatically. Only IDs do.

Comment: use `document.querySelector`

Comment: Also, don't set CSS values by composing strings on the JS side. Have your CSS contain things like ```.clockcontainer .hour { --rot: 0; transform: rotation(calc(var(--rot) * 1deg)); }``` and then on the JS side use ```document.querySelector(`.clockcontainer .hour`).style.setProperty(`--rot`, hrotation);```. Let the browser do the thing it's good at (applying CSS) and use JS only to update the value that needs updating.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the advice. Will try to implement

Answer (score 0):

See comments inline:

```js
// You must first get references to the HTML elements before they
// can be used in JavaScript
const hour = document.querySelector(".hour");
const minutes = document.querySelector(".minutes");
const seconds = document.querySelector(".seconds");

// you didn't post what the following variables are
let hrotation = -15;
let mrotation = -25;
let srotation = -35;

hour.style.transform = `rotate(${hrotation}deg)`;
minutes.style.transform = `rotate(${mrotation}deg)`;
seconds.style.transform = `rotate(${srotation}deg)`;
```

```html
<div class="clockcontainer">
  <div class="hour">Hour</div>
  <div class="minutes">Minutes</div>
  <div class="seconds">Seconds</div>
</div>
```